# Dataframe save after join is creating numerous part files

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to learn programming with Dataframes. With below code i am trying to join two CSV on a column and then saving it as a combined CSV. Running this code in SCALA IDE i am seeing almost 200 small part files as a result. Could you please help me understand what is going wrong here-

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

object JoinData {  
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext(args(0), "Csv Joining example")    
    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)  
    val df1 = sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", Map("path" -> args(1), "header" -> "true"))
    val df2 = sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark.csv", Map("path" -> args(2), "header" -> "true")) 
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    val df_join = df1.join(df2, df1("Dept") === df2("dept"), "inner") 
    df_join.repartition(1) //This is also not helping
    //Below line is generating 200 part files in Output_join folder
    df_join.save("Output_join","com.databricks.spark.csv",  org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode.Overwrite)

     }
}
```

**Program arguments used -**
    local src/main/resources/emp.csv src/main/resources/dept.csv

**CSV data being used**

```
empId,empName,Dept,salution
111,ABC,sales,mr
112,ABC,it,mr
113,ABC,tech,mr
114,ABC,sales,mr
115,ABC,sales,mr
116,ABC,it,mr
117,ABC,tech,mr

dept,name
sales,Sales of Cap
it,Internal Training
tech,Tech staff
support,support services
```

**Console Output**

```
[Stage 4:>                                                        (2 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=>                                                       (4 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=>                                                       (6 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:==>                                                      (8 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===>                                                    (11 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===>                                                    (14 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:====>                                                   (17 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=====>                                                  (19 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=====>                                                  (21 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:======>                                                 (24 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=======>                                                (26 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=======>                                                (28 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:========>                                               (30 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:========>                                               (32 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=========>                                              (34 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:==========>                                             (37 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===========>                                            (40 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:============>                                           (43 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:============>                                           (46 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=============>                                          (49 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:==============>                                         (52 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===============>                                        (55 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:================>                                       (58 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=================>                                      (61 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=================>                                      (64 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:==================>                                     (67 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===================>                                    (69 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:====================>                                   (72 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=====================>                                  (75 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=====================>                                  (78 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:======================>                                 (81 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=======================>                                (84 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:========================>                               (87 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=========================>                              (90 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=========================>                              (92 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:==========================>                             (95 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===========================>                            (98 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===========================>                           (101 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:============================>                          (104 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=============================>                         (107 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:==============================>                        (110 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===============================>                       (113 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===============================>                       (116 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:================================>                      (119 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=================================>                     (122 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=================================>                     (123 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:==================================>                    (126 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===================================>                   (129 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:====================================>                  (132 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=====================================>                 (135 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=====================================>                 (138 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:======================================>                (140 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:======================================>                (141 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=======================================>               (144 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:========================================>              (148 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=========================================>             (151 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:==========================================>            (154 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:==========================================>            (156 + 2) / 200]
[Stage 4:===========================================>           (159 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:============================================>          (161 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:============================================>          (162 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=============================================>         (164 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=============================================>         (165 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:==============================================>        (168 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===============================================>       (171 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===============================================>       (174 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:================================================>      (177 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=================================================>     (180 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:==================================================>    (183 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===================================================>   (186 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:===================================================>   (189 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=====================================================> (193 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:=====================================================> (196 + 1) / 200]
[Stage 4:======================================================>(199 + 1) / 200]
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing default partitons being used for creating number of partition while joining solved this problem.
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "2")

https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#other-configuration-options

Answer (score 0):

The reason for multiple files is because the computation is distributed. To put simply, the number of output files is equal to the number of partitions in your Dataframe/RDD. You can call repartition or coalesce on a Dataframe/RDD to change the number of partitions. '*repartition*' will shuffle the original partitions and then repartition them, while '*coalesce*' will just combine original partitions to the new number of partitions.

```
val resultDF = df_join.coalesce(10)
```

Configure the value within *coalesce* according to your specifications. I used *coalesce* instead of *repartition* is because shuffling(done by *repartition*) could be very expensive. If you just want to reduce number of partitions, coalesce would be the best way to go.

Comment: Thanks for your response. df_join.coalesce(10) is not allowed in Dataframe. And repartition is not helping. Spark is automaticall generating 200 partitions

Comment: what version of spark are you using?