# Spark coalesce vs collect, which one is faster?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using `pyspark` to process 50Gb data using AWS EMR with ~15 m4.large cores.

Each row of the data contains some information at a specific time on a day. I am using the following `for` loop to extract and aggregate information for every hour. Finally I `union` the data, as I want my result to save in **one** csv file.

```
# daily_df is a empty pyspark DataFrame
for hour in range(24):
    hourly_df = df.filter(hourFilter("Time")).groupby("Animal").agg(mean("weights"), sum("is_male"))
    daily_df = daily_df.union(hourly_df)
```

As of my knowledge, I have to perform the following to force the `pyspark.sql.Dataframe` object to save to 1 csv files (approx 1Mb) instead of 100+ files:

```
daily_df.coalesce(1).write.csv("some_local.csv")
```

It seems it took about 70min to finish this progress, and I am wondering if I can make it faster by using `collect()` method like?

```
daily_df_pandas = daily_df.collect()
daily_df_pandas.to_csv("some_local.csv")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `coalesce(1)` and `collect` are pretty bad in general but with expected output size around 1MB it doesn't really matter. It simply shouldn't be a bottleneck here.

One simple improvement is to drop `loop` -> `filter` -> `union` and perform a single aggregation:

```
df.groupby(hour("Time"), col("Animal")).agg(mean("weights"), sum("is_male"))
```

If that's not enough then most likely the issue here is configuration (the good place to start could be adjusting `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` if you don't do that already).

Comment: I am not very familiar with `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions`. Should I increase the partitions, or decrease?

Comment: There is no obvious answer for that. Typically increasing above default (200) can address some issues, especially if cardinality of the grouping expression is high.  If it is low, and you have small cluster it won't help you at all.

Comment: I finally figured out the bottleneck is the `loop`-> `filter`->`union` part. I followed your advice (`groupby` hour and animal), which reduced the time to 7 mins. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To save as single file these are options

Option 1 : 
`coalesce`(1) (minimum shuffle data over network) or `repartition`(1) or `collect` may work for small data-sets, but large data-sets it may not perform, as expected.since all data will be moved to one partition on one node

option 1 would be fine if a single executor has more RAM for use than the driver.

Option 2 : 
Other option would be `FileUtil.copyMerge()`  - to merge the outputs into a single file like below code snippet.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs._

def merge(srcPath: String, dstPath: String): Unit =  {
  val hadoopConfig = new Configuration()
  val hdfs = FileSystem.get(hadoopConfig)
  FileUtil.copyMerge(hdfs, new Path(srcPath), hdfs, new Path(dstPath), false, hadoopConfig, null)
}
```

Option 3 : 
after getting part files you can use hdfs `getMerge` command like this...

```
hadoop fs -getmerge /tmp/demo.csv /localmachine/tmp/demo.csv
```

Now you have to decide based on your requirements... which one is safer/faster

also, can have look at [Dataframe save after join is creating numerous part files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36723908/dataframe-save-after-join-is-creating-numerous-part-files)